# jQuery zoom function fails after several zoom ins and outs

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming

I am using the jQuery Zoomable maps Plugin for a WordPress site with two types of maps and legends. Under maintenance mode right now as it is not open to the public as of yet. I love its zoom in and out functionality. I even added a trigger to the legend to make links in the legend trigger zoom ins and outs on the maps which works with this extra code:

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#area-one-button').click(function() {
     $('#area-one').click();
    });
    });

But I have been having issues. After several zoom ins and outs sometimes zooming no longer works until I refresh the page or wait for a few minutes. When I click the zoom out button in the legend  I can no longer click on zoomable fields on the map as it somehow does not know I zoomed out. That is the issue. But how to solve this?

Link to all code files is here: http://javascript.pastebin.com/qpEHcDts (could only add one link)

Comment: It's advised to provide ALL relevant code. I might be wrong here but 2x .click without any code in it shouldn't be of any use.

Comment: Added link to snippet with links to all needed snippets/code and clarified myself some more too. I was only able to paste one link. NB Snippets expire after one day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a JavaScript developer I have managed to optimize the code based on the jQuery plugin as found here: http://www.gethifi.com/blog/a-jquery-plugin-for-zoomable-interactive-maps  somewhat. Here is the code in legend.js used to make certain areas clickable and to improve zoomability without delays.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#1-coast-button').click(function() {
    $('#1-coast').click();  
        });
    $('#island-1-button').click(function() {
     $('#island-1').click();
    });
    $('#water-button').click(function() {
     $('#water').click();
    });
    $('#2-coast-button').click(function() {
     $('#2-coast').click();
    });
    });
```

The basic code loaded on one map page itself is rather large, but here is one of the pop-ups loaded by code on one .html map page:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dean-smith" class="bullet" rel="441-342">&nbsp;</a> 
    <div class="popup" id="dean-smith-box"> 
        <h3>Royal X Resort</h3> 
        <div class="popupcontent"> 
            <p>Text</p> 
        </div>
        <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)"></a> 
    </div>
```

Maps do load better now and customer is pretty satisfied.